# How to display column data as row header in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

[product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3P2E.jpg)

I have 2 tables, `product` table with `productID` and `productName` :

```
Product id  productName
-----------------------
1           BUR
2           bariis
3           moos
```

and `branch` table with branch Id and branchName:

```
branchid    branchName
----------------------
B1          Sb1
B2          Cb2
```

I want to display a report in Crystal Reports like this

```
branch  BUR bariis  moos
--------------------------
Sb1      3    4      4
Cb2      2    1      5
```

Look at the image for clear understanding

Comment: i mean number in reporta how many product buyed by each branch

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the option to Insert, CrossTab...